# Disable mailing in cron globaly

Tags: linux, email, cron, sendmail

The web is full of suggestions how to disable mailing in cron like asked here [stop linux from emailing me cron errors?](https://serverfault.com/questions/185328/stop-linux-from-emailing-me-cron-errors). Is there really no global config flag I can set to disable mailing in cron for all users and all commands. I really don't want to tell all users you have to add

```
MAILTO=""
```

or

```
<command> > /dev/null 2>&1
```

to your crontab.

Comment: this is very common way to do, you can also disable `sendmail`|`postfix`.

Comment: In my experience, disabling sendmail causes the mail to build up in the queue. Not sending mail in the first place is the most ideal solution.

Comment: for centos this is the way to do it: https://serverfault.com/questions/871039/centos-7-how-to-fully-disable-cron-email-generation

Answer (score 9):

according to the man page can disable cron mail by adding `-m off` to the daemon args

> ```
>    -m     This option allows you to specify a shell command to use for sending Cron mail  output  instead  of
>           using  sendmail(8)  This command must accept a fully formatted mail message (with headers) on stan‐
>           dard input and send it as a mail message to the recipients specified in the mail headers.  Specify‐
>           ing the string off (i.e., crond -m off) will disable the sending of mail.
> ```

Comment: Nice one. On Ubuntu where can i define the daemon args?

Comment: I'm no ubuntu/upstart expert. I guess you'd have to change  in `/etc/init/cron.conf` or add in `/etc/init/cron.override`, see init [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man5/init.5.html)

Comment: Ubuntu uses vixiecron by default which does not have this option, unfortunately I am also unsure about what is the actual solution for this in ubuntu, anyone?

Comment: @Onitlikesonic As far as I'm aware there's no way to globally disable cron emails in Vixie cron - you may be out of luck unless you're willing to change your cron daemon (which is probably the easiest solution)...

Comment: @Onitlikesonic See https://askubuntu.com/questions/435454/vixiecron-doesnt-allow-disabling-of-emails-how-can-i-disable-cron-emails-globa