# Centos 7 How to fully disable cron email generation

Tags: cron, centos7

I configured email subsystem of my Centos 7 so it sends emails to outside world. Since then I started receiving about 10 emails every minutes from crond process. It is useless for me and want crond not to send any emails.

I tried to set

```
MAILTO=""
```

in /etc/crontab and in /etc/crontab.d (there's no more MAILTO=root in crontab related files) but the emails are still coming. I restarted crond service and later I restarted whole system. Nothing helps so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to /etc/sysconfig/crond and then restart crond. This will send the outputs to syslog instead of mail:

`CRONDARGS="-s -m off"`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to receive any emails from running cron jobs, you can redirect stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` or to some log file.

```
command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

You can still redirect stdout to a log file and stderr to `/dev/null` if needed.